# Problem while installing Lubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu, usb-installation

I have an old IBM T30 laptop on which I want to install Lubuntu. I created a live Pen Drive using UnetBootin. Installation was running smoothly until i got an error message saying that Grub has failed to install. It gave me three options to proceed , but none of the were responding,so I turned off the computer and then rebooted it again. Now it asked me if i wanted to erase hard disk and install Lubuntu and i clicked yes. Now the problem is that it is stuck at "Detecting file systems".

Note: I cannot connect to the internet as I have only 2 pendrive slots available and I use a dongle, so any solution which includes internet is out of reach.

Please suggest me a solution.How do I clean up this mess ? Please provide me with a step by step solution as i am not very fluent when it comes to OS matters.

Thanking you

This is the output of cat /etc/default/grub

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Next time, please don't include things like URGENT. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and start `gparted`. Go to the Devices menu and choose to create a new partition table on your hard disk (probably /dev/sda or /dev/sdb... be careful to choose wisely... based on the disk capacity displayed). Since you say this is an old laptop, it's probably BIOS, not UEFI, so choose msdos as the partition type. **This will wipe the drive.** Quit gparted.

Now you should be able to double-click on the `Install Ubuntu` icon on the desktop to continue with the install.

**Update #1:**

After creating a new msdos partition table, and restarting the install of Lubuntu, the user is still having problems writing GRUB. We're going to MD5SUM/SHA256SUM the .iso file, burn it to DVD, or rebuild his USB using `Startup Disk Creator`, and try the installation again.

**Update #2:**

Lubuntu eventually got installed with the help of `boot-repair`. The user has to boot from the GRUB command line. Once booted, `sudo update-grub` also fails. There's something wrong with the GRUB files.

**Update #3:**

The computer has hardware problems, to include a bad CMOS battery.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60685/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-urgent-help-needed-problem-while-installing).